# Reducing a 6 inch ac exhaust to 4 inch

Tags: air-conditioning

I bought a portable ac for my garage. It comes with a 6 inch hose.
I want to bore a hole thru the conderblock wall. But a 6in hole just seems too massive. I don’t want to destroy my house.  I would rather do a 4 inch hole just for the 12 inches to go thru the wall.
The ac will be about 10 inches from the wall with a 6inch pipe, then go to a reducer to make it a 4 inch pipe for another 12 inches thru the wall and out of the house.
Would I have problems here.
The original poster here talked about going 6 to 3.  6 to 4 is a 33% reduction in the cross sectional area of the hose. But it will go thru a smooth metal pipe as opposed to the extendable plastic hose that has the ridges in it and I’m sure disrupts the smooth flow of air.

Comment: Why not get a smaller ac unit ? Making the hole two small will put back pressure on the system side affects are not cooling as well, possible overheating and a shorter service life for the unit. With a 12” thick wall I might find another way to vent the system. Are you sure of your math duct work 4 to 6 I thought was a 50% increase in area. I could be wrong.

Comment: The ac is a portable 14000 btu. It’s barely enough to cool my garage, so something smaller is not an option. As for the cross section the ac has a 6 inch diameter and I want to reduce to 4.  That is a reduction of 18.84 sq inch to 12.56 sq in. Which is a reduction of 33%.

Comment: Your right, my math was wrong. Been a while since I finished school. I calculated the circumstances and not the area. So the area of the 6inch pipe is 28.26 vs 12.56 which is more than half.  Either way, my question still stands. I assume it will speed up the airflow.

Comment: Seriously, I think both of you are wrong in your calculations.  The cross-sectional area of a circular duct is A = pi * r^2.  So a 6" duct has an area of 113 in-sq while a 4" duct has an area of 50.2 in-sq.  So the 4" is only 44% as large as the 6".  But the point, is right, going from 6" to 4" is likely to cause significant performance issues with the A/C.

Comment: Huh? 6 inch diameter is 3 inch radius. 3 squared is 9.  9 x Pi is 28.26 not 113.

Comment: why don't you hook up all the pipes on the floor or on a table and run the AC ... then check for overheating and performance issues

Comment: Recommend to OP to edit the question to correct calculations of area  change. The 4" pipe has 44% of the cross sectional area of a 6". Simplest calc is (4/6)² = 0.44 or 44 %.

Answer (score 1):

Gurji, that’s what what I got also. I did calculate it after making the statement. In basic duct sizing 4 to 6 is double and 6 to 8 is double, but pi r squared is right. But I only do HVAC part time.

Cutting the area in half may speed the air up in the choke point but fans work by moving air--once the resistance increases the blades start “slipping”. I don’t remember the tech term but it’s like cavitation on a boat prop; you can put all kinds of power in but the boat goes slower until the blades bite and push the water air does similar. You can put a tachometer on the fan and watch it speed up but it is moving less air. This why duct sizing/flow is critical to set up a system.

Cutting 10% may not make a huge difference, but at 1/2 you may find your system is no longer going to cool the garage and it may shorten the service life with your compressor possibly shutting down from overheating (this can damage the refrigerant in some units).  Can you go up and out? I would not suggest cutting the flow by that much.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here quoting the difference in cross sectional area underestimate the size of the effect. For a given pressure drop, the flow of a liquid or gas through a cylindrical pipe varies as the 4th power of the radius. So a 6in pipe will have a flow rate 6^4/4^4 = 81/16 greater than the same lenth of 4in pipe - more than 5 times more!

Comment: I think the r⁴ dependence is for a viscous, incompressible fluid, but air is compressible and low viscosity so it won't be that strong. I think standard HVAC calculation must be r² dependence or even weaker. If you can shorten the hose significantly from its max length, this will compensate. Maybe a short section of 4 inch through the wall could give full performance. A gradual cone transition might work better than a shorter more abrupt transition.

Answer (score 0):

If you can shorten the hose significantly from its max length, this will compensate. Very likely a short section of 4 inch diameter through the wall could give full performance. A slightly longer, more gradual transition piece might work better than a shorter more abrupt transition.

I think the 4th power dependence of flow resistance in a circular cross section pipe is for a viscous, incompressible fluid, but air is compressible and low viscosity so it won't be that strong. I think standard HVAC calculation must be r² dependence or even weaker.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran my ac from a generator and dropped the vent from 6 to 4” which kept killing my gen.  Moved it back to a 6” and it’s running without issue.  Yea, dropping the exhaust size caused the ac to work harder which ramped up the wattage.  Problem solved